# Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in my project

Tags: codeigniter

i'm using Codeigniter 3, and i found this error message
"A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: game

Filename: home/detail.php

Line Number: 10"
and
"A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Filename: home/detail.php

Line Number: 10"

this is what's on the line that gives the error:

/images/game/" class="card-img-top" alt="" style="width: 330px">

and idk to solve this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.